Unzip multiple zip files inside each other in databricks
I have a zip file which in turn has multiple zip files inside it. I tried to write a code in databricks notebook to unzip all these files at once, but I ran into an error. So I started to unzip these one by one, but the code which worked in unzipping the first file(parent zip file) does not work for the child zip files.  Should I have to follow a different approach?
# copy to dbfs
%fs cp 'abfss://testdata@flowwesteuropedevappsa.dfs.core.windows.net/lz/INDIA_archive_LTA1_0_20240530-142643067.zip' dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads

#rename files
old_name = r"dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/INDIA_archive_LTA1_0_20240530-142643067.zip"
new_name = r"dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/sample.zip"
dbutils.fs.mv(old_name, new_name)

#unzip parent file
%sh
unzip /dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/sample.zip

#here I get multiple zip files with the message inflating: zip1.zip, inflating: zip2.zip....

#unziping one child zip
%sh
unzip /dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/zip1.zip

The error I get:
Archive:  /dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/sample.zip
replace zip1.zip? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: error:  invalid response [true # ex]

replace zip2.zip? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: error:  invalid response [it withou]

replace zip3.zip? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: error:  invalid response [t an erro].....

[y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL

(EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
CalledProcessError: Command 'b'unzip /dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/sample.zip\ntrue # exit without an error\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.


what is your error ?

You can use below code to achieve your requirement.
%sh

unzip <zipfile_path> -d <target_folder_path>

Go through the below demo.

After unzipping the first zip file, unzip the inner zip files same as above.
Result:

